# User Reputation count mismatch while searching user

Tags: support, reputation, reputation-leagues, user-search

If I search for user in [Users](https://stackoverflow.com/users) page it displays old reputation of the user.

**Example :**

> [image]

But original reputation is :

> [image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because you are searching in [Week tab](https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=reputation&filter=week). Use [All tab](https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=reputation&filter=all) instead. Search result in [Week tab](https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=reputation&filter=week&search=ak87). Search result in [All tab](https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=reputation&filter=all&search=ak87).

In *Week* tab it show only current week's reputation. In *All* tab it show all time reputation.

Comment: But ak87 got that reputation before some month ago. Then it must display 0 only know. Instead of it displays 5. Is it correct ?

Comment: @SAN3 - Where does it show 5 reputation? (in which tab?)

Comment: @hims056-In week tab.

Comment: @SAN3 - I don't see 5 reputation in [the Week tab](http://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=reputation&filter=week&search=ak87)

Comment: Ya but when i saw first time it displys 5 only. I am sure.

Comment: I don't know how did you see 5 reputation. But it show 0 reputation in [the screenshot taken by you](http://i.stack.imgur.com/YvcUG.png) (given in your question).

Answer (score 1):

The Users' page shows reputation eared for the **specified time period that was selected**(highlighted indicates the period that is selected)

[image]

Click on the "All" period to show the cumulative rep, instead of rep earned for the highlighted period

Comment: But ak87 got that reputation before some month ago. Then it must display 0 only know. Instead of it displays 5. Is it correct ?

Comment: @SAN3 it shows zero here. http://i.imgur.com/EO6ZMWi.png

Comment: Ya now it displaying 0 before it displays 5.