# Number with a user details while search user

Tags: support, reputation, users-page

What is mean why that number below a user ('565' in the attached image) while searching user in stackoverflow site?

[image]

Comment: The reputation earned during the specified period.

Comment: Related :- http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/164571/221351

Comment: When in doubt ... mouse hover.

Comment: Golden advice @AzizShaikh :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That indicates reputation earned for the particular period which can be a [week](https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=week&search=commonsware), [month](https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=month&search=commonsware), [quarter](https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=quarter&search=commonsware), [year](https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=year&search=commonsware) or [all time](https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=all&search=commonsware).